# How to set up a torrent server on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, file-transfer, bittorrent

I need to distribute extremely large files over separated networks. (Netherlands to China, and Netherlands to India), files sizes vary from 5 to 50GB. Since file is stored on several machines, and must be transmitted to several machines I would like to use BitTorrent protocol to speed up and streamline the process.

How can I set up a torrent server on my Ubuntu machine in order to achieve this, and what do I need to take into account?

I haven't found any software so far, that would be available in Ubuntu repository for this task.

Comment: Please consider that BitTorrent will only help you if have multiple clients downloading the same files and can participate in the P2P transfer. Especially in the case of China, that might be a problem.

Comment: Rename them to "Hot celebrity tits.jpg.gz" and upload the torrent file to The Pirate Bay. It'll be around the world in minutes.

Answer (score 1):

The [BitTorrent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_%28protocol%29) protocol is a peer to peer protocol.

This means it does not follow the classic client - server model.

Any torrent client software you can find for Ubuntu is also server software!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this link http://www.turnkeylinux.org/torrentserver